# Why is my database field 'not updateable'?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2013

I am developing a program which allows the user to take tests and receive a score, percentage and grade for this. These will be stored in a data table, named 'tblStudentScores'. The SQL code below aims to update the relevant record when a user completes a test, so that their latest score for that test is stored.

```
UPDATE tblStudentScores
SET Score = @Score, Percentage = @Perc, Grade = @Grade, CompletedTask = True
WHERE SpecificTaskID = @SpecID AND StudentID = @StudID;
```

When testing this SQL in MS Access, it works perfectly. However, when I attempt to use the same query as an OleDBCommand in VB.NET, nothing happens. There is no error message, but the code does not update the table either.

I thought this may be due to parameters so I explicitly declared these at the top of the query:

```
PARAMETERS @SpecID Number, @StudID Number, @Score Number, @Perc Number, @Grade Text;
```

Now, rather than nothing happening, I receive the following error message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Cannot update 'Score'; field not updateable.
```

As I have previously said, the query succeeded in MS Access's query designer, so the field must be updateable. What could be going wrong here?

EDIT: After further testing, I have found that the query does work in VB when using fixed inputs, rather than parameters. The problem is clearly therefore with the parameters, but what could the problem be?

EDIT: The entire piece of code in which I create and use the query is below:

```
 Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("PARAMETERS @Score Number, @Perc Number, @Grade Text, @SpecID Number, @StudID Number; UPDATE tblStudentScores " & _
                                    "SET Score = @Score, Percentage = @Perc, Grade = @Grade, CompletedTask = True " & _
                                    "WHERE SpecificTaskID = @SpecID AND StudentID = @StudID;", connection)


        With cmd.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@Score", score)
            .AddWithValue("@Perc", percentage)
            .AddWithValue("@Grade", grade)
            .AddWithValue("@SpecID", specificIDorder(cbxCurrentTasks.SelectedIndex))
            .AddWithValue("@StudID", id)
        End With

        connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteReader()
        connection.Close()
```

Comment: Try if positional parameters help: just use a `?` as param in the query and add the values in the correct order

Comment: OleDB parameters have to be in the correct order they appear in the sql statement.  So @Score should be first, etc. You should post your code.

Comment: Parameters in access are positional based, not named although you can name them for your own sanity. The order the parameters appear in the query is the exact same order the parameters must appear in the parameter collection. You also can't reuse the same parameter in multiple spots because it is positional. It is common to use `?` as placeholders instead of `@name` but again, this should not matter as long as the order is correct.

Comment: I still get the same error. Does the order in which I add the parameters within VB.NET itself have any effect, i.e. 'Parameters.AddWithValue...'?

Comment: Yes, but we need to see that code.

Comment: The Parameters line in the sql statement shouldn't be needed.

Comment: I can't remember if OleDB allows this: `CompletedTask = True`.  Try changing that to a parameter `@task` and pass True as the AddWithValue in the collection.  Or just `CompletedTask = -1`.

Comment: Thank you! It works now. That is strange though: I've been using parameters throughout my entire program and have only just come across a situation in which they need to be declared in a specific order. Are there any circumstances in which this isn't the case? Before I just did it based on name.

Comment: Then you got lucky or your queries are updating the wrong fields.  Behind the scenes, your named parameters @example is being turned into just a '?'.  So the order matters, 100%.

Comment: Ok, thanks again, you've been really helpful and I understand what you're saying re. parameters being in the right order. But, there's one SQL statement i wrote yesterday that doesn't fit with what you're saying, because it ends with the following: "WHERE [tblClasses/Students].StudentID = @StudentID AND tblStudentScores.StudentID = @StudentID". I only declared '@StudentID' as a parameter once here, so how could this work, for example?

Comment: Not sure I can answer that without seeing the whole code.

Comment: It is a SELECT statement that joins multiple tables together in order to get different info from each, based on the '@StudentID' criteria shown above. To declare the '@StudentID' parameter, I simply wrote: 'cmdTasksSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", id)', which I thought would apply to both instance of '@StudentID' in the WHERE part of the query. I can't move this to the chat, so I can't send you the whole code.

Answer (score 2):

Keep your data objects local so you can be sure they closed and disposed. The Using...End Using blocks do this for you even if there is an error.

Don't use .AddWithValue. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/  and https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/#comment-8442  to see the reason why. You will have to check the database for the datatypes of the fields. I just guessed.

In Access the names of parameters do not matter. The order that they appear in the sql statement must match the order that they are added to the Parameters collection.

.ExecuteReader is used to retrieve records. You want to execute an Update statement so use .ExecuteNonQuery.

I am not sure what you are doing with `specificIDorder(cbxCurrentTasks.SelectedIndex`
Is specificIDorder a Function that returns some value based on the index that is selected in the combo box? If not you need to rethink the value for that parameter.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("Update tblStudentScores 
                                Set Score = @Score, 
                                Percentage = @Perc,
                                Grade = @Grade, 
                                CompletedTask = True 
                                WHERE 
                                SpecificTaskID = @SpecID 
                                And 
                                StudentID = @StudID;", cn)
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@Score", OleDbType.Integer).Value = score
                .Add("@Perc", OleDbType.Integer).Value = percentage
                .Add("@Grade", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = grade
                .Add("@SpecID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(specificIDorder(cbxCurrentTasks.SelectedIndex))
                .Add("@StudID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = id
            End With
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```